# What's with partitioning high density drives aligned to multiples of cylinder boundaries

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning

Overheard at Fry's, a guy advising his friend to be careful in partitioning high density drives to be aligned to multiples of cylinder ( or something ) boundaries otherwise the HDD firmware/hardware would be busy constantly adjusting offsets during reads and writes?

I also heard him use the term "4K cluster sizes".

I assume almost all the >500GB drives fall under the high density category?

**Is this partitioning caveat true?**

What is the story/reason behind this ( even if this is no longer applicable for newer hardrives ) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They were talking about Advanced Format hard drives. Not all hard drives have this feature.

http://hothardware.com/Reviews/WDs-1TB-Caviar-Green-w-Advanced-Format-Windows-XP-Users-Pay-Attention/

http://www.wdc.com/en/products/advancedformat/

http://support.wdc.com/product/downloadsw.asp?sid=124

http://support.wdc.com/product/download.asp?groupid=805

Comment: Great answer! This is only for such WDC Drives or do other vendors make them as well?

Comment: Eventually all makes will move to this technology, not sure who has and has not so far, see this article....http://www.bit-tech.net/news/hardware/2010/02/02/all-new-hard-drives-will-be-4k-advanced-for/1